# Meaning of 'different and again different'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Upon those who step into the 
>   same rivers, **different and again different** waters flow.  – [Heraclitus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus#Heraclitus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a poetic and emphatic way of saying that the water flowing past "those who step into the same rivers" is constantly changing, with the implication that no two people will have the same experience when crossing the same river.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that the water is never the same, it's always different water.

Answer (score 0):

According to discussion in wikipedia, this is [Heraclitus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus)'s [resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus#Heraclitus)  of the [Ship of Theseus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) paradox.  I think that Heraclitus supports the interpretation that the river is indeed different every time encountered, while Plutarch in his [criticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutarch#On_the_Malice_of_Herodotus) of Herodotus argues the opposite.